# Modern Dungeon: How do I rebuy items?

Tags: knights-of-pen-paper-2

In the first (May 2015) issue of *Modern Dungeons*, there are two trinkets that you can buy:

- Life Scarab
- Energy Scarab

[image: Stuck on Unlocked]

However, once I have purchased them in one save-game, I can't seem to buy them again. It just stays stuck on `Unlocked`.

---

**Question:** How do I get another copy of the item?

Comment: Maybe I just don't know what I'm talking about at all, but the word "unique" typically means "there is only one" in video games.